# easiest way to make button to *.lua file CORONA SDK

Tags: button, lua, scene

What is the easiest way to make button to *.lua file?

I want to make something like : main.lua (tap button)  -->  scene1.lua  (BACK tap button) --> main.lua

I tried something like this:

```
  local storyboard = require ("storyboard")
  local scene = storyboard.newScene()

  local logo tlo = display.newImage("bg.png", 360, 640)
  local zamow = display.newImage("1zamow.png", 185, 340)
  local gadgety= display.newImage("2gadgety.png", 535, 340)
  local facebook = display.newImage("3facebook.png", 185, 700)
  local oferta = display.newImage("4oferta.png", 535, 700)
  local cennik = display.newImage("5cennik.png", 185, 1060)
  local kontakt = display.newImage("6kontakt.png", 535, 1060)

  function cennik:touch (event)
  storyboard.gotoScene("cennik", "fade", 400)

  end

  cennik:addEventListener( "touch", cennik )

  return scene'
```

after that I have runtime error:

> attempt to concatenate global 'sceneName' (a nil value)

I'm new one in Corona so please be nice :)

Comment: You have a `'` character after `return scene` . This is bad

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use widget for creating button. If cennik is your button image and scene1.lua is the next page, then code be written as

```
local storyboard = require ("storyboard")
local widget=require "widget"

local scene=storyboard.newScene()

local logotlo = display.newImage("bg.png", 360, 640)
local zamow = display.newImage("1zamow.png", 185, 340)
local gadgety= display.newImage("2gadgety.png", 535, 340)
local facebook = display.newImage("3facebook.png", 185, 700)
local oferta = display.newImage("4oferta.png", 535, 700)
local kontakt = display.newImage("6kontakt.png", 535, 1060)
local cennikBtn

local function onStartButtonRelease()
storyboard:gotoScene("scene1")
end
cennikBtn = widget.newButton {
            defaultFile="5cennik.png",
            onRelease=onStartButtonRelease
}
cennikBtn.x,cennikBtn.y =185, 1060

function scene:createScene(event)
 local group = self.view
 group:insert(logotlo)
 group:insert(zamow)
 group:insert(gadgety)
 group:insert(facebook)
 group:insert(oferta)
 group:insert(kontakt)
 group:insert(cennikBtn)
end
function scene:enterScene( event )
local group = self.view
end
function scene:exitScene( event )
local group = self.view
storyboard.removeScene("main")
end


function scene:destroyScene( event )
   local group = self.view
end


scene:addEventListener( "createScene", scene )


scene:addEventListener( "enterScene", scene )


scene:addEventListener( "exitScene", scene )


scene:addEventListener( "destroyScene", scene )


return scene
```

Comment: you must add all display element to the group in createScene function, according to the hierarchy of display.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine except for the `'` after `return scene` and your event handler needs to be like this:

```
-- For each time you tap the image, this event gets triggered twice. Make sure you only dispatch your gotoScene once!

function cennik:touch(event)

    if event.phase == "began" then
        -- This happens on finger touching
    elseif event.phase == "ended" then
        -- This happens when the finger is lifted
        storyboard.gotoScene("cennik", "fade", 400)
    end

    -- if you want to prevent the touch event from propagating (aka triggering other images touch event) you must return true
    return true
end
```